# Python script to loop through file and call api with requests then store results to text file

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping

Trying to loop through titles of movies in a text file to call API and store the response to a text file.

file contains one title on every line ex.

```
Titanic
Avatar
A Star Is Born
```

the api i am trying to use is from www.odmpapi.com

This is what i have to correctly join and create the weblink

```
import requests
import sys

prefixURL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='
suffixURL = '&apikey=xxx4s23'

text_file = open("url.txt", "w")

with open('print.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        uri = prefixURL + i.rstrip(' \n\t') + suffixURL
        print uri
        text_file.write(url)
        text_file.write('\n')

text_file.close()

text_file = open("responses.txt", "w")


with open('url.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for i in f2:
        url = i.strip(' \n\t')
        batch = requests.get(i.rstrip(' \n\t'))
        data = batch.text
        print data
    text_file.write(data)
    text_file.write('\n')

text_file.close()
```

This writes to responses.txt only the last title in the list.

Comment: There is no reference to par1 & part2 I think you need to refactor these to prefixURL & suffixURL.

Comment: @wwii Thanks. used <code></code> Newbie mistake.

Comment: You have a loop, and looks like you know how to write to a file.  What are you having problems with? Are you trying to figure out how to make the request? Have you looked through the [`urllib.requests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) docs or the [`Requests: HTTP for Humans`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) docs?

Comment: I think you might benefit from looking into [context managers](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) in order to avoid leaking file descriptors. Maybe not relevant here, but good for future.

Comment: @wwii I am doing this but it only writes to responses.txt only the last title in the list 
```
text_file = open("responses.txt", "w")

#send every uri to the api and write the respsones to a textfile
with open('url.txt', 'r') as f2:
 for i in f2:
  url = i.strip(' \n\t')
  batch = requests.get(i.rstrip(' \n\t'))
  data = batch.text
  print data
 text_file.write(data)
 text_file.write('\n')

text_file.close()
```

Comment: Yup, just noticed myself, edited.

Comment: The problem is that the data *which is unicode?!?* only stores the last title from the url.txt list, thus the response.txt is the same. I am assuming a json option would be easier to handle this but i don't even know where to start. :(

Comment: The statement `text_file.write(data)` is not *in* the loop so it only executes once. If you want it to execute for every response it needs to be indented to be *in* the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following kind of approach:

```
import requests
import sys

base_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&apikey=xxx4s23'

with open('print.txt', 'r') as f_input, open('responses.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        search_term = line.strip(' \n\t')
        url = base_url.format(search_term)
        print url
        batch = requests.get(url)
        f_output.write("{},{}\n".format(url, batch.text))
```

This writes the URL and the result into the output file. Python's `.format()` command can be used to put your search time into the `base_url` without having to split it up and use string concatenation. It works by replacing each `{}` with a passed argument.